# Finding tweets with a word contaning "_" (underscore) with twitter API

Tags: search, twitter, tweets

I am using Twitter API for searching tweets, by querying the /search/tweets endpoint.

There is a problem with my search I guess
All those words that contains "_" (underscore) in them, results in weird tweets.
For example when i query using "happy hour" Or "AAPL" the search results are perfect, But the problem occurs when search words like "CL_F" Or "FN_F"
I have googled this problem but didn't get any proper solution.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search using the Twitter REST API endpoint `search/tweets`, Twitter tokenizes the string you pass in the `q` parameter. An underscore happens to be one of characters used as a word separator. So, searching for "CL_F" will always be treated as a search for tweets containing both "CL" and "F". You will have to filter your search results for the pattern "CL_F".

Comment: thanks @Jonas for your reply. but the API does only returns tweets for either "CL" or "F", not the whole word "CL_F".

Comment: @JSs Yes, that's exactly what I am saying. The results you get will contain all combinations of "CL" and "F". From those results you will have to find the ones that contain "CL_F".